# How to download sharepoint list as csv?

Tags: python, bash, sharepoint

I am trying to download a sharepoint list as csv file. Need to automate the download through code in any language. Unable to get any leads on this. Using curl or wget, I am able to download a sharepoint document but not sure how to get a list downloaded as a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using SharePoint On-Premise, you can export list item to CSV with SSOM PowerShell:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "http://sp/sites/dev"

#Get the Target List
$list = $web.Lists["DemoList"]

#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ListItemCollection = @()

#CAML Query
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$spQuery.RowLimit = 2000
$caml=""
$spQuery.Query = $caml

#Get All List items
$listItems=$list.GetItems($spQuery)
foreach($item in $listItems) {
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $item["Title"]

    #Add the object with property to an Array
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
}
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "c:\Backup\ListData.csv" -NoTypeInformation                       

#Dispose the web Object
$web.Dispose()
```

[image]

You can trigger the PowerShell script with Windows Task Schedule so that it could run automatically.

Comment: SharePoint not provide API for bash version, I'm afraid you can not use it to download SharePoint list to csv. But give PowerShell a try, have tested it and works.